# open jquery popup from codebehind (ASP.Net VB)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have this div (popup):

```
<div class="info message">
         <h3>Informa&ccedil;&atilde;o</h3>
         <p>Mensagem informativa.</p>
</div>
```

And I have this "button" (working ok) to call the div (popup):

```
 <ul id="trigger-list">
         <li><a href="#" class="trigger info-trigger">Info</a></li>
  </ul>
```

But I don't wan't to use that button, how can I call this div (popup) from code behind? example:

```
Sub Info(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
        If ChkInfo.Checked Then

'Code to show the div (popup

Else

'Another code

End Inf

End Sub
```

Note: I'm using this: http://www.red-team-design.com/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly trigger the opening of your popup from the code-behind, however you can output code that triggers it for you using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`; `Me.ClientScript` will return you a `ClientScriptManager` object that you can use. Example:

```
    Me.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), _
        "Popup", "showMessage('info');", true)
```

which will output:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        showMessage('info');
    </script>
```

to the webpage. More information on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Source Error:


Line 101:   InformaEntidade()
Line 102:
Line 103: ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "Popup", "showMessage('info');", true)
Line 104:  'Response.Redirect("pedido_enviado.aspx?id="+TbxNome.Text)
Line 105:

Comment: My mistake, I was writing it from memory. You need to use an instance of a ClientScriptManager, which you can get from Me.ClientScript. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method. Make the div of message or popup to `runat="server"` and assign it ID. Initially you make it to visible false. So its HTML will not be generated. Now click of button to show popup this HTML will not be found, so nothing will happen.

Now you can set it `visible=true` on click event on server side. This will render HTML and code to display popup should be placed in `document.ready()`

Queries welcomed